How to determine if a hyperplane respects a set of linear inequalities
I have a set of linear inequalities in N dimensions such as:
\begin{equation}
ax + by +cz \ge d\\
ex + fy +gz \ge h\\
ix + jy +kz \ge l
\end{equation}
Given a hyperplane such as:
\begin{equation}
mx + ny + oz + p = 0
\end{equation}
How to tell if it respects the inequalities (meaning that at least a part of it goes through the polytope formed by the inequalities and that it doesn't respect them when it is entirely outside of the polytope) ?
I'm showing an example in 3D for simplicity only.
There's no restrictions on the values of x,y,z,...
I've seen answers using Farkas' Lemma, but it implies $\textbf{x} \ge 0$, which isn't the case here.
Here's an example from Desmos of a hyperplane (in 2D, so just a line) that doesn't respect the inequalities: here

What do you mean by "respects"? If you mean "when is a given hyperplane contained entirely within the subset defined by these inequalities", then the answer is basically never. For a subset $S$ defined by just one inequality, the only compatible hyperplanes are parallel to the boundary of $S$. If you have another $S'$ from a second inequality, then either their boundaries are parallel and we have the same situation as just $S$ or $S'$ alone, or they're not and $S\cap S'$ contains no hyperplanes.

My guess is that by respects, it means that the intersection is non empty. There are several versions of Farkas' lemma which do not requires $x \geq 0$. One of them should do the job.
